# No paths that contain one another from TraversalDescription

Tags: neo4j, traversal

Is this possible to configure TraversalDescription to receive collection of paths that there is no pair of paths that one is subpath of another (especially prefix of)?

Comment: please clarify your question, e.g. by a sample graph that shows what you want to do.

Comment: That would actually mean you never branch out on a path, but always follow only 1 relationship, then your `RelationshipExpander` would take care of that. Otherwise for every branch out you get shared prefixes which you don't want anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There is, using Evaluators.

Given an example graph:

```
A->B->C
```

A (reverse, in this example) traversal from C without an evaluator will return three paths:

```
{C, B->C, A->B->C}
```

Let's say I'm interested in traversal to the inputs of the graph (in this case, 'A'). I can do this by terminating and returning a path if the final node in the path is an input. I create an Evaluator object (like the following):

```
public class TerminalEvaluator implements Evaluator {

    @Override
    public Evaluation evaluate(Path path) {
        if (path.endNode().hasRelationship(Direction.INCOMING)) {
            return Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
        }
        return Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

This checks to see whether the end node of a path is an input (ie, has no incoming relationships/edges). If it is not an input, it excludes that path from the set returned by the traversal, and continues by returning Evaluation.EXCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE. If the node is an input, it includes that path in the set returned (using Evaluation.INCLUDE_AND_CONTINUE).

You will need to set the evaluator - in my toy example, given a GraphDatabaseService called 'graphDb' (I have excluded the code that drives this traversal in reverse):

```
graphDb.traversalDescription().depthFirst().evaluator(new TerminalEvaluator())
```

Running this traversal returns one path:

```
A->B->C
```

Modifying the evaluator method and also changing the traversal order (e.g. to a depth-first postorder traversal) will allow more-complex behaviours which may or may not be of use to you.